# Apple earbuds got quiet recently

Tags: audio, headphones, sound-volume

Every day for years, I've been using my Apple earbuds (old kind with TRRS jack) plugged into a laptop for video chat calls. They had worked fine until recently.

Now I need to turn the volume up to the max, and still I sometimes feel it isn't loud enough.

And no, it's not a problem with my ears.

As an experiment, I found an old phone with a TRRS port.

First, as a baseline comparison, I found old Bose headphones with a TRRS jack.

I listened to Spotify using the Bose headphones, and then I switched to listen via the Apple earbuds.

The Bose worked fine, but the Apple earbuds are too quiet.

And they didn't used to be this quiet.

I'm really surprised that somehow their volume has degraded just from normal use. I've never heard of this happening.

Is this expected?

Can I fix them somehow?

I could get an Amazon Basics replacement for $10, but I'd be curious to fix the Apple ones if possible and easy.

Comment: Even though you’re “converting” your 3.5mm TRRS jack to USB and back, it’s still originating as an analog signal from that headphone port.  Do you have a cheap USB speaker or DAC you can try?  This will bypass the built in DAC/amplifier and send a clean digital signal to USB and then to some speakers/headset.  Also, try another headset.  The free earbuds that used to come with phones are more than sufficient for this.  Also, plug your headset into a different device (without the USB stuff in between) to verify your headset is working properly.

Comment: @Allan Thanks for your comment! Right now, I'm using Bose headphones whose TRRS plug is plugged into my TRRS-to-USB-A converter, which goes to a USB-A extension cord, which goes to a USB-A switch, which goes to a USB A-to-C converter, which is plugged into the MacBook Pro. In other words, the only variable I changed was the headphones (from the Apple earbuds). And the volume is fine now! I'm 99% sure I'd already tried this and still had a volume problem. But right now I don't. So it implies to me that [continued in next comment]...

Comment: ...that the Apple earbuds have a volume problem suddenly (but aren't noticeably broken otherwise). That doesn't "feel" right to me as a diagnosis. I've never heard of headphones or speakers suddenly getting _quieter_. They don't have any _quality_ problems or damage, and I haven't abused them in any way. I'll go test them elsewhere.

Comment: @Allan I found an old phone with a TRRS port. I listened to Spotify using the Bose headphones, and then I switched to listen via the Apple earbuds. The Bose worked fine, but the Apple earbuds are too quiet. And they didn't used to be this quiet. I'm really surprised that somehow their volume has degraded just from normal use. I've never heard of this happening.

Comment: Hmm, re-reading my original question, I guess I should edit it substantially now.

Comment: Did you clean the output holes : if may become obstructed overtime and prevent sound for exiting the earbud.

Comment: @PtitXav Yes, they are clean, thanks.

Comment: Earwax? I find that a very thin layer of earwax tends to build up on the thin grille/shield covering the driver; once a significant area of is covered, it'll affect the sound, and the moment it's _all_ covered, the volume is greatly reduced. (Removing it is fiddly, but careful dabbing with some warmed-up Blu-Tak may help.)

Comment: @gidds I clean them regularly though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It’s time to replace the headset.

> I'm really surprised that somehow their volume has degraded just from normal use. I've never heard of this happening.

The signal processor inside the the enclosure that houses the buttons and microphone has probably died. The image below shows a diagram from Apple’s patent application for the earbuds. Notice the embedded signal processor.

[image]

Source: Patently Apple

It’s surprising to hear because the earbuds were usually lost or destroyed long before they failed.

Can you fix it?

Unless you have micro-soldering equipment and skills, no.  Besides, the cost to do so is far greater than just getting a new pair.  I have a pair of Sony (silicon) buds that I keep when my wireless ones are charging and besides the better fit (Apple buds hurt), they have much better bass response.  At $15 USD, it’s a very inexpensive standby.

Comment: Ahh, "It’s surprising to hear because the earbuds were usually lost or destroyed long before they failed." I love concepts like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias Thanks for this great answer!